# Adding multiple participant in a single attempt in Outlook calendar event

Tags: outlook.com

In the [Outlook web mail](https://outlook.live.com/) **Calendar event** option, If I need to add multiple participants to the event, I can add all of them in the **Required attendee** section (highlighted in the screenshot), one by one.

Currently I'm not able adding multiple participants at a time. Say if I have to add 20 participants, currently I need to enter the 20 email address separately.

Is it possible, can I add all the participants in a single attempt like adding the email address in semi-colon separated or any other way?

> [image: Required Attendee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent Outlook, the UI is changed and I can able to paste any number of participants in to the **invite attendees** field.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Outlook new look]